# Custom CharacterEscapeHandler defined in JaxBMarshaller works in Jetty, but not in Weblogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jetty, weblogic

The version of web logic is 12c.

So we were having the double & issue with the JaxBMasheller so we defined our own CharacterEscapeHandler, to essentially do nothing:

```
 marshaller.setProperty(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(),
        new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
          @Override
          public void escape(char[] ch, int start, int length, boolean isAttVal, 
                             Writer out)   throws IOException {
                               out.write(ch, start, length);
          }
 });
```

This works great in Jetty, where we do most of our testing.  However once we deploy this to a local weblogic instance, we get exceptions:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Xml Marshalling Exception
        at com.hilton.api.ws.view.xml.XmlViewRenderer.renderMergedOutputModel(XmlViewRenderer.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)

Any ideas would be welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of WebLogic are you using?  Can you post the complete stack trace?  Does it contain any `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb` references?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan TY for looking at this.  The version of weblogic is 12c, The only reference to persistence is:

Caused by: javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler value: xxx.api.ws.marshaller.xml.jaxb.JaxbMarshaller$2@1aa21bc
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.setProperty(JAXBMarshaller.java:590)
        at xxx.api.ws.marshaller.xml.jaxb.JaxbMarshaller.marshal(JaxbMarshaller.java:139)

Is that enough?

Comment: Well, if you test with Jetty, you can certainly deploy to production on Jetty as well.  My guess is you have some extra dependency that is unneeded on Weblogic, last I used it (years ago) they had a tendency to bundle javax api's with their implementations, so you may have a conflict there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebLogic 12.1.1 contains [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as the default [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) provider (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html).  That version of EclipseLink did not support the `CharacterEscapeHandlerExtension`, this support was added in EclipseLink 2.4.0 (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/06/eclipselink-24-release-available-for.html).  Here are instructions for including a newer version of EclipseLink in WebLogic:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/10/updating-eclipselink-in-weblogic.html